# Does Stack Overflow have another website beside *.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'd like to know more about Stack Overflow. Is it the framework website that is sold somewhere and everyone buy the framework? Or has the Stack Overflow framework been stolen by hackers or something? LOL

Because I have seen that the website [`id.kopea.com`](http://id.kopea.com) looks like SO. They speak Indonesian there.

Is there an explanation?

Comment: That site doesn't seem to have a topic. I started pasting question titles into Google Translate and found stuff about motorcycles, video cameras, TV show auditions, etc. The best though was  "What is the meaning of having a unified eyebrow?". A fine example of why we have rules here.

Comment: Note that, although they've removed the __meta__ link from the top of the page (unless something appears there once you've logged on), it still links to here at the RHS of the [Ask Question page](http://id.kopea.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ugh, horrifically slow site loads horrifically slow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stack Exchange is a network of Q&A sites on just about any topic you can think of that would have experts and enough questions to form a viable community. You can see new sites in progress on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), the site for proposing new Stack Exchange Q&A sites.

You can also see the current list of [Stack Exchange Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

However, the site you mention is a copy and is not affiliated with Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow in any way. Many of these copies sprung up in response to Jeff and Joel coming up with a really great idea and execution.  However, these copies never really gained in popularity because no one, IMHO, has yet to implement Q&A better than Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow.

You can copy the technology, but you can't copy the *people* behind the scenes that use that technology to create great things.

Answer (score 7):

It is one of the many copy cat sites that sprung up.

Someone copied the basic ideas of Stack Overflow and wrote their own site for it, or used one of the existing copy cats.